# Fix Symfony 3.4 Deprecated warnings PHPUnit

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, deprecated

Consider this simple example:

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class DefaultControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function testIndex()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();

        $client->request('GET', '/');

        $this->assertEquals(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

When executing this via PHPUnit I get the following warning

```
Autowiring services based on the types they implement is deprecated since Symfony 3.3 and won't be supported in version 4.0. You should rename (or alias) the "test.client.history" service to "Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\History" instead: 1x
    1x in KitaControllerTest::testIndex from Tests\AppBundle\Controller
```

How can I fix this warning since this is declared in the core of Symfony.

I am running Symfony 3.4.3

Comment: Exclude the Tests directory in your services.yaml.  Autowire is trying to wire up your test controllers.

Comment: @Cerad autowiring is only for `src/` dir - no `tests/` insight

Comment: Seems you have registered in some `services.yml` that `test.client.history` service. Maybe?

Comment: @MarçalBerga AFAIK this service is defined in the core of Symfony and not in my application logic.

Comment: Show the content of the controller please

Comment: Does your `KitaControllerTest` class load `test.client.history` via `$client->getContainer()->get(...)` ?